# Installation error with snaphu

Tags: dpkg

This is displayed when I try to install Snaphu in Linux

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The below error means that you should execute the command as root, using `sudo`

> "E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are
>   you root?

Try again using:

```
sudo command
```

e.g.

```
sudo apt install snaphu
```